# How to shift the timezone in PHP based just on a number that represents the particular hour?

Tags: php, api, timezone

I'm working with API that grabs me hourly stats. Unfortunately I cannot define timezone, so what I'm getting for the hour column is just a number that represents that value in the EST timezone.

Is there any way to convert this time information into another timezone?

Here is how the array looks:

```
array (2)
result => array (20)
|  0 => array (14)
|  |  impressions => 90177
|  |  clicks => 186
|  |  video_hits => 0
|  |  video_views => 0
|  |  value => 90.177
|  |  goals => 52
|  |  hour => 15
|  |  ctr => 0.20626101999401
|  |  cpm => 0.01
|  |  cpv => 0
|  |  vtr => 0
|  |  cpc => 0.0048482258064516
|  |  cost => 0.90177
|  |  ecpa => 0.017341730769231
```

So hour is 15 ie. 3pm I need to change the timezone of this interpretation to a local timezone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EST or EDT?  (Daylight savings matters).

I'll assume EDT.  In that case and assuming date does not matter, try:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('H', $hour, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($userTimeZone));
$userHour = $date->format('H');
```

Comment: This gives me: Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone () in..

Comment: Dammit, I forgot to change the $userTimeZone. Works perfectly now. Your are the man Devon!